# Wordpress - restrict access to certain post types

Tags: wordpress, roles

I have a Wordpress site that the client wants to set a couple of users up on, purely for creating, editing and deleting blogs. They want to assign these users the 'author' role and when they log into the admin area, they only want them to see the post type 'posts'. They do not want them to have access to media or any other custom post types. Does anyone have any ideas on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Role Editor plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) has always served me well in cases like that.

As the description says: User Role Editor WordPress plugin makes user roles and capabilities changing easy. Edit/add/delete WordPress user roles and capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had a feeling I wouldn't be able to do this directly with Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the [Groups](https://wordpress.org/plugins/groups/) plugin is what you're looking for here. I don't think that functionality is possible within stock Wordpress.

This allows you to further segregate users and permissions, restricting to posts, etc.